# Any way to get the response body during HTTP errors?

Tags: ios, swift, httpresponse, alamofire, http-status-code-403

I'm hitting an API that will occasionally throw a HTTP 403 error, and the response body can give some extra information in the form of json, however for the life of me I can't seem to get the information back out from the Alamofire response objects.  I see the information in developer tools if I hit the API via chrome.  Here's my code:

```
Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest).validate().responseJSON() {
    (response) in
    switch response.result {
        case .Success(let data):
            if let jsonResult = data as? NSDictionary {
                completion(jsonResult, error: nil)
            } else if let jsonArray = data as? NSArray {
                let jsonResult = ["array" : jsonArray]
                completion(jsonResult, error: nil)
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            //error tells me 403
            //response.result.data can't be cast to NSDictionary or NSArray like
            //the successful cases, how do I get the response body?
    }
```

I've queried pretty much every object attached to the response, but it doesn't seem to give me the response body back in the case of HTTP errors.  Is there a work-around or something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I asked this question on their github page and got an answer from cnoon:

swift 2:

```
if let data = response.data {
    let json = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("Failure Response: \(json)")
}
```

swift 3:

```
if let data = response.data {
    let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    print("Failure Response: \(json)")
}
```

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1059

I just left out the encoding part, by doing this you are able to get the response json even in the case of errors.

Comment: And now (XC8.1, Swift 3)  that encoding is : `String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)`

Comment: If you are using `SwiftyJSON`, you can also do: `JSON(response.data!)`

Comment: Swift 5:  The same format works, but you can also use a shorter encoding form with String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

Answer (score 8):

Swift 5 to get body response easily in DefaultDataResponse extension :

```
String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Comment: How do I get data of a specific value in complete response?

Comment: This print the all body response, you have to look into the raw data.